# Thymeleaf and JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate, thymeleaf, spring-el

I am new to thymeleaf. I want to integrate thymeleaf and JQuery for Clint Side Validation. Here is the code. Please have a look on this code. Where is the error and how to solve this. My JQuery file is unable to read form the location .

```
 <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">

 </script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        alert("Hi");
        $("#firstname").blur(function() {
            var un=$("#firstname").val();
            if($(this).val() == ''){
                $("#p").text("First Name is Mandatory").css("color","red");
                 $('#firstname').focus();
            }else{
                $("#p").text("");
            }
        });
        $("#lastname").blur(function() {
            var un=$("#lastname").val();
            if($(this).val() == ''){
                $("#q").text("Last Name is Mandatory").css("color","red");
                 $('#lastname').focus();
            }else{
                $("#q").text("")
            }
        });
        $("#sex").blur(function() {
            var un=$("#sex").val();
            if($(this).val() == ''){
                $("#r").text("Must choose one of them").css("color","red");
                 $('#sex').focus();
            }else{
                $("#r").text("")
            }
        });
        $("#company").blur(function() {
            var un=$("#company").val();
            if($(this).val() == ''){
                $("#s").text("Must choose one of the Company name").css("color","red");
                 $('#company').focus();
            }else{
                $("#s").text("")
            }
        });
    });
  </script>

  <style>
  .fieldError {
    color: red;
    background-color: #EB9AC5;
}

.field {
    color: #ff0000;
}

  .errorblock {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #ffEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 16px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    }
  </style>

  </head>
  <body>
        <h2>This is a Thymeleaf template</h2>
    <form action="#" th:object="${USER}" th:action="@{/my}">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <th th:text="#{enter.firstname}" /> <input type="text"
                    th:field="*{firstname}" th:errorclass="fieldError" id="firstname"/> <font
                    color="red">
                    <th th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstname')}">
                <th th:field="*{firstname}" th:errors="${USER.firstname}"
                    th:text="#{firstname.required}" class="errorblock" />
                    </th>
                </font>
                <div id="p"/>
            </div>

            <div>
                <th th:text="#{enter.lastname}">Hello</th> <input type="text"
                    th:field="*{lastname}" th:errorclass="fieldError" id="lastname"/> <font
                    color="red"> 
                    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastname')}" th:errors="*{lastname}">Incorrect
                        Choose</p>
                </font>
                <div id="q"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <th th:text="#{enter.sex}" /> <input type="radio" th:field="*{sex}"
                    th:value="Male" th:errorclass="fieldError" id="sex"/>Male <input
                    type="radio" th:field="*{sex}" th:value="Female"
                    th:errorclass="fieldError" />Female
                 <font color="red">
                    <th th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('sex')}">
                <th th:field="*{sex}" th:errors="${USER.sex}"
                    th:text="#{sex.required}" />
                    </th>
                </font> 
                    <div id="r"/>
            </div>

            <div>
                <th th:text="#{enter.company}" /> <select th:field="*{company}"
                    th:errorclass="fieldError" id="company">
                    <option th:value="Symphony" th:text="#{enter.company1}" />
                    <option th:value="TCS" th:text="#{enter.company2}" />
                    <option th:value="VMWare" th:text="#{enter.company3}" />
                </select> <font color="red">
                    <th th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('company')}">
                <th th:field="*{company}" th:errors="${USER.company}"
                    th:text="#{comapny.required}" />
                    </th>
                </font>
                <div id="s"/>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button type="submit">Subscribe me!</button>
            </div>

        </fieldset>

    </form>

</body>



</html>
```

Comment: a fiddle would have been better..

Comment: I didn't get Bhavik. Could u plz elaborate ?

Comment: How this is related to Spring EL ?

Comment: In Thymeleaf , We can able to write the Spring EL(As Thymleaf = HTML5+Spring EL). kocko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side validation isn't a good idea. JavaScript can be disabled in browser and validation won't work. Read about [field errors](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Thymeleaf-Spring3.html#field-errors). When form is submitted, controller method can check if form is `@Valid` and you have all errors in `BindingResult`. You can make something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/my", method = "POST")
    public String postForm(final @Valid MyForm form, final BindingResult bindingResult, final ModelMap model) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "my";
        }
        model.clear();
        return "redirect:/success";
    }
```

Comment: To be more correct: client-side validation can be a good idea - but only if you do independent server-side validation too. The bad part is only if you have client-side validation exclusively.

Comment: @Iwo kucharski your response did not answer the question: why is wrong with the jquery code and why is it not been called?

Comment: @leeCoder thanks for pointing it out 6 years after the message was wrote ;) Honestly I do not work much with Thymeleaf anymore, but first thing I would do is to put all script code inside `/*<![CDATA[*/ ... /*]]>*/`. Hope this helps if anyone still uses jquery in 2020 ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have few suggestions that can help resolve why the JQuery code is not been called.

Put the `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` at the last line before the `closing body tag` and/or before any jquery based libraries that may require the use of jQuery library. This is become the jquery should be loading last after html codes are done loading.

Check this part. This seems to me as unwanted repetition and use only of the line of code below:

```
   var un=$("#sex").val();  //this line is the same as $(this).val()
   if($(this).val() == ''){  ....
```

Hope this help someone looking for similar solutions